# how can i get pictures from instagram using specific tags and locations

Tags: api, instagram

So, I am trying to get a bunch of pictures from Instagram using their API.

How can I specify the pictures I want to get, **using both tags and location**, not just one of them.

I tried to go to the endpoints listed on Instagram page, but it does not show any endpoint for both of them.

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask a good question :)

Comment: ...What the heck is that last bit? There's a reason StackOverflow has limits. Don't skirt them. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and fix this question.

Comment: I am sorry about that, it is my first time on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API currently to get photos by both tags and location, you can use location search API get photos and then compare the tags in photos.

Here is an implementation of this feature: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map

search for a location and then filter by keyword, the filter applies only for the photos loaded on the page, not all instagram photos at that location, you have scroll and load a bunch of photos and then filter with keyword.